# Iterative pull requests from the same branch?

Tags: git, github

Say I create a branch that is ready to be merged with master, so I create a pull request. Eventually this pull request is accepted.

Say that I continue working on that branch to improve it in some way. Can I do a pull request again later from the same branch? and if I do so:

1. Would this confuse git, GitHub in any way?
2. Is this a proper worfkflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fine, and I often do. A branch can have many pull requests over its lifetime, so GitHub won't get confused.

We use PRs for to merge functionality into the develop branch for long-running features as it becomes stable. We *could* merge back, delete the branch and create a new one, but that feels like a lot of extra work for no benefit :).

We also make heavy use of the [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) workflow, which I'd recommend looking into.